# Can't add numbers using the void method

Tags: c#

I'm trying to add 25 to stdNumber (anything typed in a text box) using a void method..

```
public void IncreaseStudents(int num)
    {
        int.Parse(textBox3.Text + num);
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        School s1 = new School();

        s1._schlName = textBox1.Text;
        s1._schLevel = textBox2.Text;
        s1._stdNumber = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

        listBox1.Items.Add(s1._schlName);
        listBox1.Items.Add(s1._schLevel);
        listBox1.Items.Add(s1._stdNumber + IncreaseStudents(25)); //throws an error here
```

As you can see School is a class name, SchName and schLevel are objects and are using string, while stdNumber is using int.

I can't figure out how to add numbers using void. It worked with int in the method but I need to use void. Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use a void? If you want to add two numbers, they must be numbers, not a number and a void. Make the method return a numeric type.

Comment: A `void` function does not return a value, so it has no result to be used in an operation.

Comment: you can use out values to get a value back from a void function.

Comment: I was instructed to do that. I know I can use the int method returning numbers but I'm only allowed to use void.

Comment: Update global variable inside `IncreaseStudents` if you really need void as return type. ```this.count = int.Parse(...) +  num;```

Comment: @VadimB That didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make `IncreaseStudents` work the way you want, you need to change two things: You need to *return* a value, meaning it can't be `void`. And you need change the way you turn `textBox3.Text` into an integer. You don't parse the whole expression, `textBox3.Text + num`; `num` is a number already. All you need (or want) to parse is `textBox3.Text`, because it's a string. And we'll use a different way of parsing, so that if the text doesn't represent a number, it will fail politely instead of throwing an exception.

```
public int IncreaseStudents(int num)
{
    int n;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out n))
    {
         return n + num;
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Not a number: " + textBox3.Text);
         return num;
    }
}
```

Then this line of code should work fine -- unless `s1._stdNumber` is something weird that you can't add to.

```
listBox1.Items.Add(s1._stdNumber + IncreaseStudents(25));
```

But that's not the assignment. The assignment says you have to use void. So, another try:

```
public void IncreaseStudents(int num, out int result)
{
    int n;
    if (int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out n))
    {
         result = n + num;
    }
    else
    {
         MessageBox.Show("Not a number: " + textBox3.Text);
         result = num;
    }
}
```

And call like this:

```
int result = 0;
IncreaseStudents(25, out result)

listBox1.Items.Add(s1._stdNumber + result);
```

Silly, but if your instructor wants that, that's what he wants.

Comment: OP has stated that they have to use a return value of `void` for this assignment.

Comment: Thank you, but there is something wrong with the math. I get double the number + 25..

Comment: @AbdullahHassan You'll have to see where you're getting the numbers from. You were giving it 25 so I gave it 25. It's adding that to the numeric value of the text box text, whatever that is.

Comment: @EdPlunkett I have checked through the entire code multiple times and there isn't one single statement where the typed number gets * 2.

Comment: @AbdullahHassan I can see that my code isn't doing that. I can't see your code.

Comment: I have replaced the void method with int as you've stated in the first example (just to check) and it somehow worked, there isn't a doubled number. Also, the original post basically shows my entire code excluding the School class.

Comment: @AbdullahHassan Were you initializing `result` to zero? Can I see the code where you call it and it doubles?

Comment: Here you go: http://i.imgur.com/kForhEw.png .. I did as you have mentioned in the example. Nothing else was added. My guess is that it has to do with using void?

Comment: Here is a screenshot of the output. http://i.imgur.com/jBLyABC.png .. Any entered number becomes times 2 + 25.

Comment: @AbdullahHassan Nothing to do with "using void". No, the problem is that you're *already* parsing `textBox3.Text` and assigning it to `s1._stdNumber`, and *then* adding that to the result of `IncreaseStudents`. Either start `s1._stdNumber` at zero, or don't add `textBox3.Text` in `IncreaseStudents`

Answer (score 2):

Use an `out` parameter.

Example:

```
public void AddNumbers(int a, int b, out int result)
{
    result = a + b;
}
```

Use it like this:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 3;
int result;
AddNumbers(a, b, out result);
Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints "8"
```

Note: This is abusing the `out` parameter somewhat, and I imagine this assignment is just to teach you how to use it. In practice, never use an `out` parameter when a return value will do the job.

EDIT: Your set of restrictions is absolutely bizarre, but the `out` parameter should still work for you.

```
public void IncreaseStudents(int num, out int result)
{
    result = num + int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    School s1 = new School();

    s1._schlName = textBox1.Text;
    s1._schLevel = textBox2.Text;
    s1._stdNumber = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);

    int result;
    IncreaseStudents(25, out result);

    listBox1.Items.Add(s1._schlName);
    listBox1.Items.Add(s1._schLevel);
    listBox1.Items.Add(result); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!  but I'm not able to add a number in a method with the variable inside the button class.

Comment: @AbdullahHassan What does that mean? Are you not allowed to change the code in your `button1_Click` method?

Comment: @AbdullahHassan The reason I ask is because it's not possible to use `s1._stdNumber + IncreaseStudents(25)` when `IncreaseStudents` has a return value of `void`. So your code is going to have to change somewhere.

Comment: I am allowed to change the code, but I cannot use `stdNumber` in the parameters of `IncreaseStudents` method.

Comment: Thank you again, Abion. But the result also seems to give me a doubled number + 25 which is quite strange..